# Splitting up scraped text into coordinates

Tags: python, csv, parsing, scrapy, coordinates

Hi I am looking for some help in splitting up a piece of text (such as below) into coordinates using python.  I am using scrapy to get the data in this d variable, which I am hoping to parse through to create a list of paired x and y coordinates to export via a csv file. ideally it would be most useful to be able to manipulate the y values as I place them into the list because they are not in their final form (I have an equation to change the y's into the value I want).  I have all the code to scrape and export as a csv, but looking for some help on a parsing method for this text.

```py
d="M 0 118.46933333333334 L 7.4949494949495 118.98666666666666 L 14.989898989899 113.16666666666667 L 22.484848484848 109.028 L 29.979797979798 108.12266666666667 L 37.474747474747 104.63066666666667 L 44.969696969697 96.35333333333334 L 52.464646464646 95.836 L 59.959595959596 92.86133333333333 L 67.454545454545 91.956 L 74.949494949495 89.628 L 82.444444444444 86.524 L 89.939393939394 86.524 L 97.434343434343 81.60933333333334 L 104.92929292929 82.256 L 112.42424242424 82.77333333333334 L 119.91919191919 81.73866666666667 L 127.41414141414 83.67866666666667 L 134.90909090909 74.108 L 142.40404040404 79.66933333333334 L 149.89898989899 76.436 L 157.39393939394 81.86800000000001 L 164.88888888889 75.14266666666667 L 172.38383838384 77.47066666666667 L 179.87878787879 81.60933333333334 L 187.37373737374 80.05733333333333 L 194.86868686869 86.78266666666667 L 202.36363636364 82.12666666666667 L 209.85858585859 85.10133333333334 L 217.35353535354 85.10133333333334 L 224.84848484848 86.65333333333334 L 232.34343434343 83.93733333333334 L 239.83838383838 87.42933333333333 L 247.33333333333 92.08533333333334 L 254.82828282828 91.82666666666667 L 262.32323232323 95.18933333333334 L 269.81818181818 95.836 L 277.31313131313 94.02533333333334 L 284.80808080808 92.47333333333334 L 292.30303030303 91.43866666666668 L 299.79797979798 86.912 L 307.29292929293 89.88666666666667 L 314.78787878788 90.016 L 322.28282828283 94.80133333333333 L 329.77777777778 87.94666666666667 L 337.27272727273 95.44800000000001 L 344.76767676768 92.21466666666667 L 352.26262626263 90.92133333333334 L 359.75757575758 89.36933333333334 L 367.25252525253 87.04133333333334 L 374.74747474747 90.53333333333333 L 382.24242424242 83.67866666666667 L 389.73737373737 79.54 L 397.23232323232 81.35066666666667 L 404.72727272727 81.35066666666667 L 412.22222222222 82.12666666666667 L 419.71717171717 83.93733333333334 L 427.21212121212 85.10133333333334 L 434.70707070707 85.36 L 442.20202020202 95.44800000000001 L 449.69696969697 91.05066666666667 L 457.19191919192 90.27466666666668 L 464.68686868687 86.26533333333333 L 472.18181818182 86.13600000000001 L 479.67676767677 86.00666666666667 L 487.17171717172 87.30000000000001 L 494.66666666667 81.99733333333334 L 502.16161616162 80.96266666666668 L 509.65656565657 85.23066666666666 L 517.15151515152 81.60933333333334 L 524.64646464646 83.29066666666667 L 532.14141414141 75.14266666666667 L 539.63636363636 72.168 L 547.13131313131 69.71066666666667 L 554.62626262626 76.17733333333334 L 562.12121212121 65.31333333333333 L 569.61616161616 73.33200000000001 L 577.11111111111 72.03866666666667 L 584.60606060606 81.092 L 592.10101010101 76.69466666666668 L 599.59595959596 73.84933333333333 L 607.09090909091 70.09866666666667 L 614.58585858586 72.68533333333333 L 622.08080808081 60.01066666666668 L 629.57575757576 61.17466666666667 L 637.07070707071 63.373333333333335 L 644.56565656566 84.196 L 652.06060606061 84.45466666666667 L 659.55555555556 83.93733333333334 L 667.05050505051 83.42 L 674.54545454545 74.36666666666667 L 682.0404040404 84.71333333333334 L 689.53535353535 81.86800000000001 L 697.0303030303 90.14533333333334 L 704.52525252525 90.016 L 712.0202020202 90.53333333333333 L 719.51515151515 140.71466666666666 L 727.0101010101 145.37066666666666 L 734.50505050505 143.56 L 742 142.784 L 742 194 L 734.50505050505 194 L 727.0101010101 194 L 719.51515151515 194 L 712.0202020202 194 L 704.52525252525 194 L 697.0303030303 194 L 689.53535353535 194 L 682.0404040404 194 L 674.54545454545 194 L 667.05050505051 194 L 659.55555555556 194 L 652.06060606061 194 L 644.56565656566 194 L 637.07070707071 194 L 629.57575757576 194 L 622.08080808081 194 L 614.58585858586 194 L 607.09090909091 194 L 599.59595959596 194 L 592.10101010101 194 L 584.60606060606 194 L 577.11111111111 194 L 569.61616161616 194 L 562.12121212121 194 L 554.62626262626 194 L 547.13131313131 194 L 539.63636363636 194 L 532.14141414141 194 L 524.64646464646 194 L 517.15151515152 194 L 509.65656565657 194 L 502.16161616162 194 L 494.66666666667 194 L 487.17171717172 194 L 479.67676767677 194 L 472.18181818182 194 L 464.68686868687 194 L 457.19191919192 194 L 449.69696969697 194 L 442.20202020202 194 L 434.70707070707 194 L 427.21212121212 194 L 419.71717171717 194 L 412.22222222222 194 L 404.72727272727 194 L 397.23232323232 194 L 389.73737373737 194 L 382.24242424242 194 L 374.74747474747 194 L 367.25252525253 194 L 359.75757575758 194 L 352.26262626263 194 L 344.76767676768 194 L 337.27272727273 194 L 329.77777777778 194 L 322.28282828283 194 L 314.78787878788 194 L 307.29292929293 194 L 299.79797979798 194 L 292.30303030303 194 L 284.80808080808 194 L 277.31313131313 194 L 269.81818181818 194 L 262.32323232323 194 L 254.82828282828 194 L 247.33333333333 194 L 239.83838383838 194 L 232.34343434343 194 L 224.84848484848 194 L 217.35353535354 194 L 209.85858585859 194 L 202.36363636364 194 L 194.86868686869 194 L 187.37373737374 194 L 179.87878787879 194 L 172.38383838384 194 L 164.88888888889 194 L 157.39393939394 194 L 149.89898989899 194 L 142.40404040404 194 L 134.90909090909 194 L 127.41414141414 194 L 119.91919191919 194 L 112.42424242424 194 L 104.92929292929 194 L 97.434343434343 194 L 89.939393939394 194 L 82.444444444444 194 L 74.949494949495 194 L 67.454545454545 194 L 59.959595959596 194 L 52.464646464646 194 L 44.969696969697 194 L 37.474747474747 194 L 29.979797979798 194 L 22.484848484848 194 L 14.989898989899 194 L 7.4949494949495 194 L 0 194"
```

It has been some time since I familiarized myself with parsing text via python so any suggestions appreciated! Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Please be sure to [format your code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) so that they can be read easily. Additionally, more details about what the data you're working with is and what you're wanting to do with it would make it easier to help you. Perhaps include a small sample of expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I am making 3 assumptions here:

1. The `M` and `L` don't matter, you just want the coordinates.
2. You don't care in which format you get the `x` and `y` coordinates.
3. You didn't provide the equation to modify `y` so I just added 1 to `y` as a modification.

You can use regular expressions to get you answer as follows:

```py
import re

# I didn't use the entire `d` string you provided to not fill up the answer with loads of text.
d = """"M 0 118.46933333333334 L 7.4949494949495 118.98666666666666 L 14.989898989899 113.16666666666667 L 22.484848484848 109.028 L 29.979797979798 108.12266666666667 L 37.474747474747 104.63066666666667 L 44.969696969697 96.35333333333334 L 52.464646464646 95.836 L 59.959595959596 92.86133333333333 L 67.454545454545 91.956 L 74.949494949495 89.628 L 82.444444444444 86.524"""

# this is the regular expression that will match `M/L` `X` `Y`
pattern = re.compile(r"[A-Z] (\d*\.?\d*) (\d*\.?\d*) ")

matches = re.findall(pattern, d)

coordinates = list()
for x, y in matches:
    # you didn't provide the y modification equation so I just added 1
    y = float(y) + 1
    x = float(x)
    coordinates.append((x, y))
```

So you can modify the `y` in the loop with your equation.
The end result will be a list `coordinates` containing tuples with the `x` and `y` values.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know why the first coordinate is labelled with an "M" instead of an "L"? It seems to just have each coordinate in the syntax: `{M/L} {X} {Y}` (or maybe Y, X), I can probably help out with that info.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like You are trying to get coordinates data from svg `<path`> tag.

`data = d.split(" ")`

convert your string into following list `[ 'M', '0', '118.469', 'L', '7.494', '118.986', 'L', '14.98', '113.166', 'L', '22.484', '109.028', .... ]`

`y_str = data[2::3]` 
 select only `y` values   `[ '118.469', '118.986', '113.166', '109.028',...]` from list

`y = [float(number) for number in y_str]` 
  convert str list into list of numbers

`x_str = data[1::3]`
`x = [float(number) for number in x_str]`
the same for x

`res = list(zip(x,y))`

finally get paired x,y list

Your data have only move to `M` and line to `L` command.
this code will not work in case if your `path` tag will contain Bezier (`C` or `Q`) and elliptic arc `A` lines command